Let's keep tag excerpts crunchy
Tag excerpts show just the first couple sentences when a user is tagging a question. Many of our tag excerpts start with “collects questions about <tag-name>…”, “should be used to collect questions about <tag-name>…”, or similar phrases.
When we tag a question or hover a tag to read more about it, we already know that we are looking at a tag and that tags label questions. Instead of repeating the basic function of tags in each excerpt, let's start with relevant information right away instead of wasting the first few words a user gleans.
E.g. the tag excerpt for address started with “should be used for Bitcoin addresses”.

but could instead start with a brief summary of the purpose of addresses which also establishes that we talk about Bitcoin addresses rather than IP-addresses or physical addresses

As a second example, the wallet tag excerpt was “should be used for questions that pertain to wallet software. A wallet software is a piece of software which manages users' keypairs, addresses, and transactions. Wallet software also allow a user to send and receive Bitcoin.”

Which I replaced with “A wallet manages a user's private keys. Wallet software is used to send and receive Bitcoin. It also keeps track of the user's transactions, addresses, and balance.”

Let me know what you think.
